# Tag to send the modifier user

Tags: fix-protocol

I am using FIX 4.4 and would like to know which tags can be use to send and receive the Name or email of the user who has made the last update?
I found 523 and 553 but would like to know if there are more appropriate tags.

Please note that I cannot use custom tags.

Comment: In which context? Update to what? Orders?

Comment: Sorry .. update of orders (execution report), deal(security status), order cancel replace and reject

Comment: `553/Username` is normally used on the `Logon` message to authenticate a user. I'd suggest to look at the `Parties` component with the `453/NoParties` repeating group.

Comment: Ok thank you I will try with that

Comment: In the 453 relating group there is 523 already listed in my description. Is it possible to use the 553 outside of a logon message?

Comment: In FIX it is always possible to use tags in other messages if you agree on this with your counterparty. However, it should make sense to do so. If you want to transmit mail addresses (as stated in your question) look at the `802/NoPartySubIDs` repeating group in the `453/NoParties` repeating group. It has a `803/PartySubIDType=8` which is meant for an email address.